# exit(1) in signal handler just gets caught as SystemExit as there is nothing to it

Tags: python, signals

I have an application that looks like this:

```py
while True:
    try:
        self.try_to_read_usb_device()
        break
    except:
        time.sleep(1)
```

I also have an `SIGALRM` handler which is supposed to exit the program in case it got stuck somewhere:

```py
def alarm_signal_handler(signal, frame):
    # Something went wrong
    exit(1)
```

However the `exit(1)` just get caught by the try/except and gets discarded as this is what that specific `except` does.

This is quite unexpected to me.

In the complete application there will be a lot of try/except and I don't see myself adding

```py
except SystemExit:
    exit(1)
```

or something for all of them.

Any idea how I should handle that use-case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### The dirty way

You can use [`os._exit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os._exit) instead of `sys.exit`.

Note that this has obvious drawbacks exactly *because* it won't go through an exception:

> Exit the process with status n, without calling cleanup handlers, flushing stdio buffers, etc.

#### The proper way

I'd recommend to instead change your exception handling to catch only things inheriting from `Exception`, because `SystemExit` *doesn't* inherit from `Exception` for precisely this reason, so it won't be caught accidentally:

```py
except Exception:
```

See also the [`SystemExit` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#SystemExit):

> This exception is raised by the `sys.exit()` function. It inherits from `BaseException` instead of `Exception` so that it is not accidentally caught by code that catches `Exception`. This allows the exception to properly propagate up and cause the interpreter to exit.

This also applies to `KeyboardInterrupt` by the way - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will be caught by `except:` but not by `except Exception:`.

It's illustrated pretty well in the exception hierarchy diagram in the Python docs, which you can find [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy).